# jquery datatable render function for date

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery plugin - Datatable , to render the gridview with sorting, searching & pagination.

I am able to get it to work, except when i try to render the date.  Without any render filter, my date shows in the datatable as

> /Date(1489005452663)/

and the date is stored in the database as date and timestamp

> 2017-02-14 15:52:02.177

When i include the render for my date in jquery, the datatable doesnt populate anything and it shows blank table.

Here is the code I am using to populate my datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $.ajax({
           url: 'ReportService.asmx/LoadReport',
           method: 'post',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data) {
               $('#datatable').dataTable({
                   data: data,
                   columns: [
                       { 'data': 'CMS_CONTRACT_NUMBER' },
                       { 'data': 'submissionid' },
                       { 'data': 'file1status' },
                       { 'data': 'file2status' },
                       {
                         'data': 'datesubmitted',
                         'render': function (data)
                          {
                              var date = new Date(parseInt(data.substr(6)));
                              var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                             return date.getFullYear() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getDate ;
                            //  return data;
                          }
                       }
                   ]
               });
           }
       });
   });
```

I am not sure what's causing the render inclusion not to populate any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you call the `getDate` method by including the parentheses:

```
return date.getFullYear() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getDate();
                                                         // ^
```

With the parentheses it should work:

```js
var data = '/Date(1489005452663)/';
var date = new Date(parseInt(data.substr(6)));
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
console.log(date.getFullYear() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getDate());
```

There must be something else happening that we can't see.  Of course, you could also try a different method of parsing out the numbers:

```js
var data = '/Date(1489005452663)/';
var date = new Date(+data.replace(/\D/ig,""));
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;

console.log(date.getFullYear() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getDate());
```

Comment: I would have left that as a comment, but I don't have enough rep. It seems I can leave comments here, though ;)

Comment: @Ron Can you include an actual example?  The easiest thing to do would be to set a breakpoint in the debugger and ensure `data` is what you think it is.

Comment: thanks for your approach of doing the testing. I tried your method and i am able to get the formatted date & time, but i am wondering what is causing the date from the database not getting included in my function, ...

Comment: after debugging, i find that there are some null values in the date column, that's causing it not to populate any data ....

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable failure, so in those cases you definitely don't want want to return from the function early.  `var dateVal = +data.replace(/\D/ig,""); if (!dateVal) return;` something like this

Comment: Thanks @mike, after including the check for null date, now, it's gracefully displaying in the specified format.

Comment: My comment was mistyped -- the "don't want" shouldn't have been there.  It should have read, *you **definitely want** to return from the function early*, but glad you understood ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in `render` function:

```
return (moment(new Date(data)).isValid() ? moment(new Date(data)).format('MMMM Do, YYYY @ h:mm:ss a') : ' -- ');
```